# Trying To Publish An Action To Facebook Timeline Using The Build-in Object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish an action to facebook timeline using the Build-in object types video.episode and video.tv_show.
The 'object' i'm trying to publish is http://www.trackmyeps.com/episode/QI/S09E06_53027.html.

- I do have the publish_action permission
- As far as i know all the meta tags are correct
- I do have an active access_token
- I made some dummy object/action/arregations in my app (but i'm not using those as i'm using the build in object types and actions).

So i have no idea why i'm getting this unknown error. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
The print_r of the exception:

> FacebookApiException Object (
>       [result:protected] => Array
>           (
>               [error] => Array
>                   (
>                       [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
>                       [type] => OAuthException
>                   )
>
> ```
>     )
>
> [message:protected] => An unknown error has occurred.
> [string:private] => 
> [code:protected] => 0
> [file:protected] => /mnt/web7/11/43/51874443/htdocs/classes/base_facebook.php
> [line:protected] => 1039
> [trace:private] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => Array
>             (
>                 [file] => /mnt/web7/11/43/51874443/htdocs/classes/base_facebook.php
>                 [line] => 744
>                 [function] => throwAPIException
>                 [class] => BaseFacebook
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [error] => Array
>                                     (
>                                         [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
>                                         [type] => OAuthException
>                                     )
>
>                             )
>
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [1] => Array
>             (
>                 [function] => _graph
>                 [class] => BaseFacebook
>                 [type] => ->
>                 [args] => Array
>                     (
>                         [0] => /me/video.watches
>                         [1] => post
>                         [2] => Array
>                             (
>                                 [tv_episode] => http://www.trackmyeps.com/episode/QI/S09E06_53027.html
>                                 [access_token] => i've removed this
>                             )
>
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Meta data on the webpage:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"               content="132426653493733"> 
             <meta property="og:type"                 content="video.episode"> 
             <meta property="og:url"                  content="http://www.trackmyeps.com/episode/QI/S09E06_53027.html">
             <meta property="og:image"                content="http://epguides.com/QI/cast.jpg">
             <meta property="og:title"                content="Inventive (S09E06)">
             <meta property="og:description"          content="No episode discription found">
             <meta property="video:release_date"      content="2011-10-14 00:00:00">
             <meta property="video:duration"          content="1800">
             <meta property="video:series"            content="http://www.trackmyeps.com/series/QI_143.html">
```